# Панель поиска с помощью swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку (Value of type 'Pills' has no member 'contains').
Нужно сделать поиск по списку.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
    @State private var searchText : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            SearchBar(text: $searchText)
            ForEach(userData.pillss.filter {
                self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.contains(self.searchText)
            }) { pills in

                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PillsDetail(pills: pills)
                        .environmentObject(self.userData)
                ) {
                    PillsRow(pills: pills)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `contains` является встроенным методом массива (`userData.pillss`), `$0` у вас очевидно является объектом класса/структа `Pills` и не является массивом

- вам нужно в нем либо добавить публичное свойство, содержащее текст для сравнения, скажем `var text: String`, тогда

  ```
  self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text == self.searchText
  ```
- или добавьте в `Pills` метод `contains` и уже в нем производите сравнение

  ```
  func contains(_ text: String) -> Bool {
      self.text == text
  }
  ```